# Adding small image tag over newly added content in php

Tags: php, html

Actually i want to add a small gif image over another image for the latest added games. Means i have games site like this http://www.girlsgogames.com/ .. i want to add the NEW tag over an image for my recently uploaded games. Means whatever the latest 5 games i upload, for those games i want to add the new tag automatically...means whenever i upload new 5 games the new tag will come over on the latest games. I want to acheive this using php mysql..can anyone help me in this case..i have added small image for reference.[image]

I have added this code. please check it once..

```
    <div style="width:980px; float:left">
                <div class="upperLeftCorner980"></div>
                <div class="upperCenter980">
                  <div style="text-align:left">Today's Top <?php echo NEW_GAME_TITLE;?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="upperRightCorner980"></div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <div class="centerLeft980">
                  <div class="centerRight980">
                    <div class="boxContentDiv" style="height:100%">
                    <div style="width:373px; height:309px; float:left; margin-left:10px; padding-top:30px">
                    <center>
                    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
/* 336x280, created 1/21/11 hope page new games */
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>

                    </center>
                    </div>
                        <div style='padding:3px'>
                            <?php
                       $gameQuery = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16");

                                while ($gameRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($gameQuery)){
                                                                    if ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'fr'){
                                            $description = $gameRow['description_fr'];
                                        }else{
                                            $description = $gameRow['description'];
                                        }

            ?>
<div style='float:left; width:180px; height:160px; margin:5px;' title="<div style='font-size:12px; font-weight:bold'><b>Description:</b> <?php echo $description;?></div><div style='font-size:12px; font-weight:bold'><b><?php echo GAME_TIME_PLAYED_TITLE;?>:</b> <?php echo $gameRow['time_played'];?></div>" class='tooltip'>


<?php
    $x = 0;
foreach($gameRow as $game) {
```

//Below is line 65 where i am getting error..at exactly `echo "<div class=''gameBGBox'>"`

```
echo "<div class='gameBGBox'><a href='<?php echo $confRow['sitePath'];?>play/<?php echo str_replace(' ','_',$gameRow['name']);?>'><img src='<?php echo $confRow['sitePath'];?>games/images/<?php echo $gameRow['img_100x75'];?>' width='180' height='135' border='2' alt='<?php echo $gameRow['name'];?>'/></a>";
    if($x<5){
    echo '<div class="new"></div>';
    }
    echo "</div>";
    $x++;
}
?>               </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <div style='clear:both'></div>
                           </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="lowerLeftCorner980"></div>
                <div class="lowerCenter980"></div>
                <div class="lowerRightCorner980"></div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <div style='height:5px'></div>
                <!-- Separator -->
        </div>
```

I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\main.php on line 65

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retreive the list ordering by the id:

```
select * from games order by id desc
```

Then loop trhough it:

```
<ul id="game_list">
    <?php
        $count = 0;

        foreach($games as $game) {
            echo '<li><img src="' . $game['img_location'] . '" />';

            if($count < 5) {
                echo '<div class="new"></div>';
            }

            echo '</li>';
            $count++;
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
#game_list {
    list-style: none;
}

#game_list li {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.new {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80px; /* w of new banner img */
    height: 80px; /* h of new banner img */
    background: url(../img/new_banner_img.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for your logic. I tried your logic and implemented but the thing is i am getting some error. See my my error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\main.php on line 65

Comment: Hi Sven, actually the problem with this code is it applies the "new.gif" to each game five times. may be need to re work it..any suggestions...

Comment: Hey, did you implemented the `foreach` function correctly? Because the loop is correct. It sounds like that you have an `for` loop instead of an `if` statement.

Comment: Actually i modified my post. if you want to check my code please check my main post where u added the code. and as you said i implemented the code whatever you said but the thing here is it loops through for each div for five times and applies to all the new games for which i queried from database with limit 16. the logic applies to all the games..

Comment: I didn't saw that you updated the question. I see that you use a `while` loop as a `if` statement. `While` doesn't work with `else`. So change that into a `if{} else {}` Can you show me the HMTL of one item generated by the foreach?

Comment: Oops...i forgot to add the if in the above..this line of code has to be there..its there in my code..if ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'fr'){..but still its not working...

Comment: Do you have an HTML example of the game list? (one gameBGbox div will be ok)

Comment: hi sven please re check my main post..its my actual code.i am working on my localhost.i hope u cant see my demo.

Comment: Yes I can see. But I want the code that is generated by this code :) And what is on line 65?

Comment: hi sven, please check once my main post where i added my actual code with where i am getting the error means at line 65

Comment: Hey, sorry didn't saw the update. The error is before the line 65. Can you add post lines 63 to 64?

Comment: these are the lines ... <?php
    $x = 0;
foreach($gameRow as $game) {

Comment: strange.. What happens when you replace (out comment it) the code in the `foreach` with an `echo "here i am! <br/>";`? Do you still get the error?

Comment: When i echo the normal text it shows out but the loop applies to all the newly added games. but when i add this <div> content it rises error..

Comment: Try to build the div step by step. So first add the dic container and test if it still works, now add the next small update and test again. repeat this until you got the code line that triggers the error.

Comment: Yes i have tried the error comes when the first anchor tag <a href='<?php echo $confRow['sitePath'];?> exists.

Comment: So it's only the anchor tag that's causing the error? If so, try to replace all the PHP into some static HTML to check if the error is in the PHP part.

Comment: yes i have removed all the php code from the anchor tag and its showing the content but loop applies to each div five times..see my main post i added the image..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14059/discussion-between-sven-and-phphunger)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like:

```
<?php 
for($x=0;$x<count($GAMES_ARRAY);$x++) {
?>
<div class="game-images">
     <img src="cover.png"/><? if ($x<5) {?><img src="new.gif" style="position: relative; left: 10px; z-index: 1;"/><? } ;?>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

So the "new.gif" will overlayed onto the cover.png.

Edit: You have to play little bit with "left" and "top" values.

Comment: I edited my answer. loop through your database output and add the "new.gif" to the first 5 games.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo elements like ::before and ::after in your css to acomplish this. [Here](http://girliemac.com/blog/2012/03/24/making-chupa-chups-using-css3-pseudo-elements/) is a small tutorial on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will work in all browsers

Use z-index to overlay one image over the other

```
<div >
     <img src="banner.jpg" style='position:absolute; z-index=0;'/>
     <img src="new.gif" style="position: fixed; right: 10px; z-index: 1;"/>
</div>
```

Update for the Latest five games

use a query such that the games are ordered in descending order , then if count is less than 5 then overlay new.gif else dont.

Query

```
select * from GameTable order by id desc
```